# How to show/hide an area within Razor View in ASP.NET MVC programmatically 

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

I want to programmatically show/hide a group of fields (label, textfield, checkbox) on Razor view (.cshtml), based on a model value. The model is access to the view.

Thanks

Comment: do you want to conditionally render some html or you want to render it anyway and show hide using js on different browser events

Comment: Muhammad Adeel Zahid, conditionally render some html on server side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide a div element depending on Model value? MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046108/how-to-hide-a-div-element-depending-on-model-value-mvc)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In your Razor View cshtml:

```
@if(Model.RevealSecretPlans)
{
    <div>
      Giant frikkin laser
    </div>
}
```

This of course assumes `RevealSecretPlans` is a boolean

Comment: Upvoting for the comedy as much as the excellent answer