# How to hide a div element depending on Model value? MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is what I have at the moment

```
 hidden="@(Model.IsOwnedByUser||!Model.CanEdit)"
```

This works fine on Chrome but doesnt hide on Internet Explorer

I tried also visibility set false but no luck.

then I found out another style as below

```
style="@(Model.IsOwnedByUser||!Model.CanEdit)?'display:none'""
```

I could not get it worked. What is the correct format to hide an element with Razor syntax?

Or I would use Jquery to hide the element. but is it actually possible print out jquery statement that would hide the element on page load?

Comment: What is wrong with the second statement? except the fact that you have two `"` at the end and are missing an 'else' (`:''`)

Comment: style="@(Model.IsOwnedByUser || !Model.CanEdit)?'display:none':'display'" when I see the source code

Comment: this is the return : style?'display:none':'display'

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The below code should apply different CSS classes based on your Model's `CanEdit` Property value .

```
<div class="@(Model.CanEdit?"visible-item":"hidden-item")">Some links</div>
```

But if it is something important like Edit/Delete links, you shouldn't be simply hiding,because people can update the css class/HTML markup in their browser and get access to your important link. Instead you should be simply **not Rendering** the important stuff to the browser.

```
@if(Model.CanEdit)
{
  <div>Edit/Delete link goes here</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was missing a syntax when I have 2 conditions.

Comment: <div style="display:@(Model.CanEdit ? "block":"none" )"></div>

you can also use above code to show or hide html element.

Comment: Second method is using logic in view which is not an appreciated method.

Answer (score 42):

Try:

```
<div style="@(Model.booleanVariable ? "display:block" : "display:none")">Some links</div>
```

Use the "Display" style attribute with your bool model attribute to define the div's visibility.

Comment: Please [format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your answer to improve its readability.  Explaining why this works and/or providing references would also improve your answer.

Comment: I shouldn't prefer using this for sensitive information. Because `Display:none` can be disabled in a browser through Inspect Element. using an `@if` statement as stated in Shyju's answer is safer.

Comment: @Steven, We can still change the class value through inspect... or can change the display property from class name.. so hardly matters

Comment: If you place `display:none` either in style or in a css class, it'll still be rendered. You would want to prevent the div from rendering,

Answer (score 4):

Your code isn't working, because the hidden attibute is not supported in versions of [IE before v11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden)

If you need to support IE before version 11, add a CSS style to hide when the hidden attribute is present:

```
*[hidden] { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is specifically about hiding the div but if you don't do anything else with the div (in JavaScript for example) then you can just not include it in the output of the view by using the Razor `@if` syntax.

```
@if (Model.IsOwnedByUser && Model.CanEdit)
{
<div>Some Links</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me....

```
<div style="@(Model.YourBoolean?"":"display: none;")">
```