# Hide a field on form when a field value is Yes/No

Tags: c#, html, razor

Below is the code from my `edit.cshtml`

I need to hide by `SubClient_ID` field if value in `Group_Rollup_Flag` is Yes and unhide when `Group_Rollup_Flag` is null.

How should I do that ? How would I write an `if` statement for this ?

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MasterClient_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("MasterClient_ID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control input-block-level" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MasterClient_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubClient_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("SubClient_ID", null, "--Select--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control input-block-level" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubClient_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RebateClient_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("RebateClient_ID", null, "--Select--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control input-block-level" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RebateClient_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot understand the code. You can format it

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Comment: Just `@if ( Group_Rollup_Flag )`, Razor supports server-side if-s easily.

Comment: See this [@if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046108/how-to-hide-a-div-element-depending-on-model-value-mvc) solution.

Comment: Thanks all, this is fixed. @if did the work.